# Angular / Jquery selectors result an error when running Protractor

Tags: jquery, angularjs, highcharts, protractor, karma-runner

I'm getting an error when running Karma + protractor on Angular Project.
I tried few different methods for selecting elements, they all result in an error.

**I'm seeking a way to make it work / to ignore this function when running the tests.**

This is the line that fails the tests:

```
var chart = angular.element(document.querySelector("#chart2")).highcharts();
```

This line results in :

> TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating
>   'angular.element(document.querySelector("#chart2")).highcharts()')

I tried several different methods:

I change the line to:

```
var chart = $("#chart2").highcharts();
```

and got the follwing error:

> ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $

I also tried to change this line to:

```
var chart = angular.element("#chart2").highcharts();
```

And then i got the follwing error:

> Error: [jqLite:nosel] Looking up elements via selectors is not
>   supported by jqLite! See:
>   http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.element
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.4/jqLite/nosel

The important thing is all 3 options are working on angular.

**I'm seeking a way to make it work / to ignore this function when running the tests.**

Any idea that might work?

Comment: Seems like jquery isn't being loaded during your tests.

Comment: @iliacholy do you have any idea what should i change or add in order to load it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These options will probably work if you have jQuery available. Looks like your test is using the angular built-in jqLite, where those functionalities are not available.

> Angular can use jQuery if it's present in your app when the application is being bootstrapped. If jQuery is not present in your script path, Angular falls back to its own implementation of the subset of jQuery that we call jQLite. - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element

Maybe try adding jQuery to your karma config? Loading jQuery before angular should work.

e.g. in your karma config:

```
files: [
'libs/jquery.js',
'libs/angular.js'
]
```

Comment: i need to add those files to protractor and not not karma, any idea how to add jquery / angular to karma?

Answer (score 0):

You might get traction out of something in the neighborhood of

```
expect(element(by.xpath('//highcharts')).isPresent()).toBe(true);
```